# Named capture in regexp

Tags: regex, r, regex-group, capturing-group

I need the ability to capture groups in regular expressions using names in r. I test the code explained in this site [[Rd] Named capture in regexp](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2011-February/060086.html) and the example works without problem. I try to adapt this code to solve simple regular expression.

```
(xxxx)(?<id>\w{4})(?<number>\d{5})
```

For more details see the code [here](https://regex101.com/r/zW1rG7/1)

I try to do it in r

```
regex =  "(xxxx) (?<id>[0-9A-Za-z]{4}) (?<number>[0-9]{5})"
notable = "xxxxcn0700814"
regexpr(regex,notable,perl = TRUE)
```

and it was my output for this code

```
[1] -1
attr(,"match.length")
[1] -1
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
attr(,"capture.start")
        id number
[1,] -1      -1   -1
attr(,"capture.length")
        id number
[1,] -1      -1   -1
attr(,"capture.names")
[1] ""        "id" "number"
```

I can see what is the problem with this because this code is similar to the code of web page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what exactly is the problem here? I see the captured names in the output. Looks like you have spaces in your regular expression but not in your target. Is that the "problem"?

Comment: Add `(?x)` at the pattern start or remove spaces from the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make the whitespace in the PCRE regex formatting, just use the `(?x)` inline modifier:

```
regex =  "(?x)(xxxx) (?<id>[0-9A-Za-z]{4}) (?<number>[0-9]{5})"
          ^^^^
```

See the [R online demo](https://ideone.com/UdRVd9)

If you want to match a literal space with this modifier, you will have to escape it, or use inside a character class. If you need to match any whitespace, use `\s` shorthand.

If you do not need all these "prettifying" stuff, just remove the spaces from your pattern since without `(?x)` they are meaningful:

```
regex =  "(xxxx)(?<id>[0-9A-Za-z]{4})(?<number>[0-9]{5})"
```

Note the literal `#` symbol must also be escaped to denote a literal `#` symbol.
Also, whitespace inside character classes (`[...]`) is treated as a literal whitespace and you can use `(?#:...)` comments inside the PCRE regex pattern with the `(?x)` modifier.